# Error connecting to localhost after npm hardhat run it shows network lost

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

I am new to deploying smart contracts with hardhat and am following a tutorial.  However, after running `const contract = await ethers.getContractAt("Decentratwitter","0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3")` I get the following error. Any ideas on how to fix connection issues?

```
avinash@avinash-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~$ cd twitter
```

avinash@avinash-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~/twitter$ npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network hardhat
Decentratwitter deployed to: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
avinash@avinash-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~/twitter$ npx hardhat console --network localhost
Welcome to Node.js v14.19.3.
Type ".help" for more information.

> const contract = await ethers.getContractAt("Decentratwitter","0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3")
> Uncaught HardhatError: HH108: Cannot connect to the network localhost.
> Please make sure your node is running, and check your internet connection and networks config
> at getContractAtFromArtifact (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:337:19)
> at getContractFactoryByAbiAndBytecode (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:280:21)
> at getSigners (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:45:20)
> at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
> at GanacheGasMultiplierProvider.request (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:306:23)
> at GanacheGasMultiplierProvider._isGanache (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:317:30)
> at HttpProvider.request (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:80:29)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at HttpProvider._fetchJsonRpcResponse (/home/avinash/twitter/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:205:15)

```
Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `npx hardhat node` in your terminal. Leave the process running.
2. Open a new terminal window.
3. Run `npx hardhat run [script-name] --network localhost`

Hope it helps!